# Delete JSON object after each iteration

Tags: python, json, file, generator

I have a large json file `(6GB)` which contains simple key and value pair like

```
 { "0546585b451000" : "5",
   "0546585b451000111222" : "10"
 }
```

I am using `ijson` to parse this file and perform some operation on each object

I want to delete every object from `json` file itself after completion of iteration.

```
with open(SOURCE_JSON_FILE, 'r') as fd:
     parser = ijson.parse(fd)
     for prefix, event, value in parser:
         if event == 'number':
            print('prefix={}, event={}, value={}'.format(prefix, event, value))

         ## Delete this row from json file now
```

My intention is to minimize the size of actual `json` file so that if in case process breaks in between, i can continue with remaining keys.

What should be the approach to achieve this? apart from dumping done objects into another file or database.

help is appreciated

Comment: Apparently the best way to delete first few lines in python needs you to load the whole file into the Memory and writing the rest of the file again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364396/how-to-delete-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-python . This way it will be very expensive. You can consider using a simple shell script to achieve this rather than python.

Comment: I suppose, rewriting the file each time you remove a small portion of it isn't a very good idea. It will generate unnecessary high workload on your drive subsystem. If needed, try saving the last processed key somewhere to know the offset in the original file.

Comment: as @Gautam says, don't try to parse the json structure, since you need to read it completely into memory. Instead, do a 'string' search and replace operation on the file

this is more brittle, but consumes much lkess memory.

A quick and dirty idea, based on your data:
 `perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/="},"} print "$1\n" if /(\{\s*\"0546585b451000\"\s*:[^,]+\,\s*\"0546585b451000111222\"[^}]+\})/mi' < DATA.json`